# Direct-to-S3 upload error

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3

I'm having a sudden issue with a direct-to-s3 setup I've been working with on a Heroku app. I used this tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) and had everything working with this code for the back-end:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const awsconfig = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY, 
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET, 
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET }
});

router.get('/sign-s3', function(req, res) {
  const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
  const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
  const s3Params = {
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.end();
    }
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      url: `https://${process.env.S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
    res.end();
  });
});
```

The issue is, this was working perfectly to upload a user profile picture until I tried using the same setup for another application. I have three Heroku apps running that all need to use the same bucket for uploads since the applications share data. As soon as I tried using the same setup (including reusing the AWS Key and AWS secret) BOTH apps started throwing this error when I tried to upload:

```
{ 
[CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    originalError: {
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED *IP LISTED HERE*' 
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, both return undefined json to the front-end of the app. I've tried reconfiguring permissions on the bucket several different ways and also creating a separate IAM User profile for use with the second app, but I still can't get either one to accept the upload again. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? My only guess is that by allowing the apps to share the AWS Keys I created some kind of permissions error, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

As always, any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: While arguably not a best practice, there's nothing at all about using the same credentials in multiple applications that should make things stop working.  Is it possible that you messed up your environment, so that `process.env.S3_BUCKET` now returns an incorrect value?  What's the IP address shown? Do you recognize it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I could see that maybe with the new setup, but the first app was working fine and has been unchanged the entire time so that's what's really confusing me. It only stopped working once I added the same credentials to another app. I wasn't able to locate the IP for the S3 instance I'm using so I'm not sure how to check against that, but when I log the bucket name it all seems correct.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Actually just figured it out... just my luck but the Heroku tutorial seems to have been updated literally in the middle of this project. Apparently, the AWS KEY and SECRET vars are now loaded automatically on s3 initialize, so my guess is my trying to define them with `new AWS.Config` was what was messing everything up. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this who may have used an older version of the Heroku tutorial, the issue was that it had been updated and now the AWS config vars are loaded automatically on with `new.aws.S3();`.

So defining them as I was above with:

```
const awsconfig = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY, 
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET, 
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
```

was throwing an error - possibly overwriting the vars that had already been set. Hope this helps someone!